# jwPlayer not working properly in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jwplayer

I want jwPlayer to play for 2 sec. and then pause.
I implement this functionality but its not working properly in IE 8.
Its working in mozilla and chrome.
Anybody suggest me how to do it?

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jwplayer('GridMessageBoard__ctl3_dvMsgContent').setup({
        var jwplayerid = this.id;
        flashplayer: 'mediaplayer/player1.swf',
        file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOfdboHvshg',
        width: 400,
        height: 300
        });
    jwplayer(jwplayerid).play();
    window.setTimeout("PausejwPlayer('"+jwplayerid+"')",1500);

});

function PausejwPlayer(objID)
{
   jwplayer(objID).pause(true); 
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="GridMessageBoard__ctl3_dvMsgContent" style="display:block;width:100%;"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: means sometimes when i refresh the page it display black screen

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your configuration in `setup` (and remove your other call to `window.setTimeout`):

```
events: {
  onPlay: function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      jplayer(jwplayerid).pause(true);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that it was just a timing issue, where the player was maybe still starting or buffering, etc. - and the whole 1.5 or 2 seconds had elapsed before the player ever had a chance to play.  This will start the timer only after the player has actually started playing.

(I don't see where `jplayerid` is being set, so I'm assuming you have it defined elsewhere and above your current code.)

If this doesn't work by itself, add some debugging lines within the function call I provided here to see if the setTimeout is getting called, and that you still have a valid player ID, etc.

Comment: i tried but still not working.actually sometimes its working fine and  sometimes its display just black screen

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem

```
primary: "flash",
```

this code will solve your problem :)